# My sc5-styleguide doesn't update anymore

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-sass

So yesterday it was working like a charm, I went home, got to work this morning and it didn't work.
I'm creating a styleguide for a website. I hope that some of you guys can help me.
Here's my code

gulpfile.js

```
var paths = {
    styles: 'assets/scss/source/**/*.scss',
    cssDest: 'frontend/css',
    styleguide: 'styleguide'
};

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch(paths.styles, ['styles', 'styleguide']);
});

gulp.task('styles', function() {
    return gulp.src(paths.styles)
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.cssDest))
        .pipe(concat('all.min.css'))
        .pipe(cssnano())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.cssDest))
        .pipe(livereload());
});

gulp.task('styleguide:generate', function() {
    return gulp.src(paths.styles)
        .pipe(styleguide.generate({
            title: 'My Styleguide',
            rootPath: paths.styleguide,
            appRoot: '/styleguide',
            overviewPath: 'README.md',
            server : false,
            disableEncapsulation: true,
            styleVariables: 'assets/scss/_variables.scss',
            extraHead: [
                '<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>',
                '<script src="/frontend/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>',
                '<script type="text/javascript" src="/frontend/js/lib.min.js"></script>',
                '<script type="text/javascript" src="/frontend/js/all.min.js"></script>'
            ],
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.styleguide));
});

gulp.task('styleguide:applystyles', ['styles'], function() {
  return gulp.src([
        "frontend/css/bootstrap.min.css",
        "frontend/css/main.css"
    ])
    .pipe(styleguide.applyStyles())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.styleguide));
});
```

When I run gulp watch and save some scss, I get this:

[image]

What is undefined!?! And how do I fix it?

**EDIT**

The problem occurs in styleguide:generate

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten this terribly helpful error message a number of times now, as well.

Most of the time it pops up for me when I've given two blocks the same identification. If I have two sections with **Styleguide 1.1**, for example, then the Styleguide shows the error in a large red, rendered section in the page header of the styleguide itself. However if I have further nested children with the same id like this: **Styleguide 1.1.3** then all I see is a *undefined* in the console and a dead webpage where my lovely styleguide once was.

Another issue that cost me several hours appeared when I tried setting variables in SCSS with the !global suffix. I found the fix when I stumbled upon this article: [Advanced techniques for the SC5 styleguide generator](http://www.alleyinteractive.com/blog/advanced-techniques-for-the-sc5-styleguide-generator/). The key was in one of the last paragraphs, *SC5 Exclude and Compiler Errors*. Here it mentions adding problematic sections of code in ignore blocks. This is described in the readme file under [Ignore parts of the stylesheet from being processed](https://github.com/SC5/sc5-styleguide#ignore-parts-of-the-stylesheet-from-being-processed).

I'm currently using sc5-styleguide version 0.3.44 with gulp 3.9.1.

I haven't looked into the SC5 Code myself, but hoped my experience might in some way help others who stumble upon this question.

For what it's worth, always being particularly careful to avoid duplicate IDs and generously using `// styleguide:ignore:start` and `// styleguide:ignore:end` around 'problematic' code blocks has worked for me.

Comment: It would be helpful to post more about the solution here.   Just linking to a resource that helped you isn't super helpful.   This answer is 90% "I have the problem too" and 10% helpful link.